# How can I get a overflow-x scrollbar to appear on a <ul> inside a <div> with position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML where `#admin-menu-page` is always just a bit
smaller than my browser window and the div with a class of `block-border` is a bit
smaller than that.

In the middle of these I have a  which can have many elements. 
How can I make it so that a scrollbar appears when the number of elements
can no longer fit inside the `div` with class block-border?  Note I tried 
putting overflow-x: auto on the `<ul>` and also on #menu-1 and this did 
not seem to work.

article {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10.2rem;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

```
article #admin-menu-page {
   position: absolute;
   top: 2rem;
   left: 2rem;
   bottom: 2rem;
   right: 1rem;
}

article #admin-menu-page > div {
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
}

<body>
 <article>
    <div id="admin-menu-page">
       <div class="block-border"> sidebar" id="menus">
          <div id="menu-1">
             <ul class="menu">
                <li>XX</li>    
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <article>
</body>
```

Comment: Some little remarks: you have a nesting problem near <div class="block-border"> sidebar" id="menus"> and is a performance issue to write 'article #admin-menu-page' since ids in a html page are unique

Comment: Oh and the last article tag isn't closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a height in combination with overlow-y: auto in order to work

### CSS:

```
   #admin-menu-page > div {
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     overflow-y: auto;
     height: 60px;
   }
```

See a sample here (the border was added for debugging purposes) :

http://jsbin.com/EbiHEmO/1/edit

And see what happens when you add more bullets into that ul:

http://jsbin.com/EbiHEmO/2/edit